# Swift NSCoder NSKeyArchiver: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

Error causes a crash when using NSCoder to archive custom objects in array from json.

Error causing crash:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code of error: I included the full code in retrieveData()

```
// NSCoding *Error causes Crash here*
let blogList: NSObject = ((jsonArray[i]) as! NSObject).value(forKey: "blogList") as! NSObject
```

MainController.swift

```
// Retrieving Data from Server *Clean Code*
func retrieveData() {

    let getDataURL = "http://blogtest.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

            // Create Blog Object
            let bID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! String
            let bName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogName") as! String
            let bStatus1: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus1") as! String
            let bStatus2: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus2") as! String
            let bURL: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogURL") as! String
            let bType: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogType") as! String
            let bDate: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogDate") as! String
            let bPop: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogPop") as! String

            // NSCoding *Error causes Crash here*
            let blogList: NSObject = ((jsonArray[i]) as! NSObject).value(forKey: "blogList") as! NSObject

            // Add Blog Objects to mainArray
            mainArray.append(Blog(blogName: bName, andBlogStatus1: bStatus1, andBlogStatus2: bStatus2, andBlogURL: bURL, andBlogID: bID, andBlogType: bType, andBlogDate: bDate, andBlogPop: bPop, blogList: blogList as! [Blog]))
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Blog.swift - Handles the Blog custom objects

```
import UIKit

class Blog: NSObject, NSCoding {

// Strings
var blogName: String
var blogStatus1: String
var blogStatus2: String
var blogURL: String
var blogID: String
var blogType: String
var blogDate: String
var blogPop: String
var blogList : [Blog] // NSCoding

// Converting Strings into Objects
init(blogName bName: String,
     andBlogStatus1 bStatus1: String,
     andBlogStatus2 bStatus2: String,
     andBlogURL bURL: String,
     andBlogID bID: String,
     andBlogType bType: String,
     andBlogDate bDate: String,
     andBlogPop bPop: String,
     blogList : [Blog]) // To NSCoding
{

    self.blogName = bName
    self.blogStatus1 = bStatus1
    self.blogStatus2 = bStatus2
    self.blogURL = bURL
    self.blogID = bID
    self.blogType = bType
    self.blogDate = bDate
    self.blogPop = bPop
    self.blogList = blogList // NSCoding
    super.init()
}

// NSCoding
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init (coder : aDecoder)
    self.blogName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogName") as! String
    self.blogStatus1 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus1") as! String
    self.blogStatus2 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus2") as! String
    self.blogURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogURL") as! String
    self.blogID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogID") as! String
    self.blogType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogType") as! String
    self.blogDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogDate") as! String
    self.blogPop = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogPop") as! String
    self.blogList = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogs") as! [Blog]
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(blogName, forKey: "blogName")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus1, forKey: "blogStatus1")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus2, forKey: "blogStatus2")
    aCoder.encode(blogURL, forKey: "blogURL")
    aCoder.encode(blogID, forKey: "blogID")
    aCoder.encode(blogType, forKey: "blogType")
    aCoder.encode(blogDate, forKey: "blogDate")
    aCoder.encode(blogPop, forKey: "blogPop")
    aCoder.encode(blogList, forKey: "blogs")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash have nothing to with NSCoder. Check in debugger or log the value of value(forKey: "blogList"). It most likely don't exist. Can you give sample response of what you are getting in network response.

Also it's my suggestion not to use forced unwrapping instead use optional with guard as server response can not be trusted and this could start causing crash in future

You should change constructor to below

```
init?(id:String, info:[String:AnyObject]){
    guard let name = info["blogName"] as? String, let blogStatus1 = info["blogStatus1"] as? String  ... so on .. else { 
        return nil
    } 

    blogName = name
    .
    . initialize all field like these

    // for  blog list
    var tmpBlogList = [BlogList]()
    if let tmpBlogListInfo = info["blogList"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
    {
        for info in tmpBlogListInfo
        {
             let childId = info["blogID"] as? String
             if let blog = Blog(id:childId, info) {
                  tmpBlogList.append(blog)
             }
        }
    }
    blogList = tmpBlogList
}


//Replace mainArray.append(Blog(blogName: bName, andBlogStatus1: bStatus1, andBlogStatus2: bStatus2, andBlogURL: bURL, andBlogID: bID, andBlogType: bType, andBlogDate: bDate, andBlogPop: bPop, blogList: blogList as! [Blog]))
if let blog = Blog(id: bID, info: blogList) {
      mainArray.append(blog)
}
```

Comment: So the crash is happening because "blogList" is empty? I have to disable NSCoder to print out 'mainArray' which is where the network stores the objects. I can't print out "blogList" because it crashes in that line. Printing mainArray without using NSCoder. `This is mainArray [<BlogTest.Blog: 0x600000194770>, <BlogTest.Blog: 0x600000194840>, <BlogTest.Blog: 0x600000194910>, <BlogTest.Blog: 0x6000001949e0>, <BlogTest.Blog: 0x600000194ab0>]` (Shortened it because wouldn't fit)

Comment: How can I prevent the crash?

Comment: You can print         print("index: \(i) , content: \(String(describing: jsonArray[i]))") before reading blogList.

Comment: You cast blogList as! [Blog], it will also cause crash. You are downloading a data from server and parsing data it using JSONSerialization and than and than reading blogList from json. It make blogList into array of Blog object. It most likely is in format of [[String:AnyObject]]

Comment: Okay so I changed the code around, cleaned `retrieveData()`, added `UserDefaults.standard` to save `archivedData`, checked to see if a key exists and it does, and its not crashing anymore for the error that this post said but at the line `self.init (coder : aDecoder)` its crashing saying "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Should I make a new post or replace this one?

Comment: Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531300/swift-self-init-coder-adecoder-is-crashing-app-with-exc-bad-access Would appreciate your help, got me this far.